# Phoenix Framework: How can I pass :infinity value as parameter for Ecto.query

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I pass `:infinity` value as parameter for `Ecto.query`.

```
from(query, limit: ^limit, offset: ^offset)
```

Since the `limit` value here is `:infinity`, I am getting the following error.

```
value `:infinity` in `limit` cannot be cast to type :integer in query
```

How can I make a query where there is no limit for such a query (because I can get too many results as a result of the query)?

Is there any proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `limit` from the statement and you will get all of the records for the table.

```
from(query, offset: ^offset)
```

Or you could just query the table:

```
Repo.all(User)
```